# Crystal Reports - Flow Layout view of records

Tags: crystal-reports, report

All,

I am using Crystal Reports in VS2010.  I want to execute a query that lists records as row, and as a sub-query as you like, display a record within something that resembles a Flow Layout (.Net/Java style).

I am executing a stored procedure to get my data in one, for example:

```
SELECT Table1.Field1 AS Title
       Table2.Field1 AS RowRecord1
       Table2.Field2 AS RowRecord2
       Table3.Field1 AS DataRecord

FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.table1_id
JOIN Table3 ON Table2.id = Table3.table2_id
```

So Table1 is the top level parent, Table2 is an intermediate, Table3 has my child data that I want to display differently - not in a row.

So dummy data in select will look like:

```
Title      RowRecord1    RowRecord2   DataRecord
My Test    Some Row1     Test 1       D1
My Test    Some Row1     Test 1       D2
My Test    Some Row1     Test 1       D3
My Test    Some Row1     Test 1       D4
My Test    Some Row1     Test 1       D5
My Test    Some Row2     Test 222     D1
My Test    Some Row2     Test 222     D2
My Test    Some Row2     Test 222     D3
```

So I want the overall report to look like as follows:

```
**My Test** 

Some Row1   Test 1

D1   D2   D3   D4
D5

Some Row2   Test 222

D1   D2   D3
```

DataRecord will fill the section up from left to right (single value) - in a Flow Layout.

Ideally I want to know how to do this in Crystal if at all possible.  If not I will listen to alternative ideas or solutions.  I've tried a few things to no avail and not found anything on line as yet.

Thanks,

Andez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

First group in Crystal by `Title` , `RowRecord1`, `RowRecord2`

Then create three formulas:

**In the deepest group header put:**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global numberVar count := 0;
StringVar ConCat:= "";
```

**In detail section:**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
StringVar ConCat;
Global NumberVar count;

   if ((count Mod 4) = 0) then
       ConCat:= ConCat & {DBTABLE.DataRecord} & ChrW(13) //adds a line break
   else 
       Concat := Concat & {DBTABLE.DataRecord};
   count := count + 1    

   ConCat
```

**In group footer**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
StringVar ConCat;
Concat;
```

Comment: Hi Robert, I am trying this.  I have copied the formulas as is.  I get an error on the count saying not enough arguments have been given to the function.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I've changed the name of count to count1.  I have added Global numberVar count1 in the Detail section formula.  It displays D1 for the first group 5 times and in the group footer.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Will keep trying.  Thanks Andez

Comment: I've updated a bit. Global Numbervar was missing in the middle formula and of course incrementing the count variable. I havent tried this code in CR, i just presented my approach to this. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Robert, sussed it now thanks.  I've hidden the Detail section and the first part in the detail formula are now:  WhilePrintingRecords;
global numberVar count1:= count1 + 1;
StringVar ConCat;

Comment: As a long shot, is it possible to add boxes dynamically.  I know this just appends to a string and outputs it, but just on an off chance.  Thanks again