# Crystal Reports Row to columns without crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports, report, rows

I need to convert information from multiple rows to show in a single Row.

My table looks like this

> **KEY
>   Type
>   Value**
>
> One 
>   Date1
>   May10
>
> One 
>   Date2
>   May11
>
> One 
>   Date3
>   May12
>
> TWO 
>   Date1
>   June20
>
> TWO 
>   Date2
>   June21
>
> TWO 
>   Date3
>   June22

I need it to look like this in the report

> **Key*
>   Date1
>   Date2
>   Date3**
>
> One
>   May10
>   May11
>   May12
>
> TWO
>   June20
>   June21
>   June23

I'm running Crystal Reports 2008. I can't use a Cross-Tab report because I have many other columns that will be added to the report..

Comment: You may try to achieve the effect by using global vars and WhilePrintingRecords. You can take the general approach from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11966665/534877

Comment: you can still use a cross-tab with additional columns. can you explain a little further? are there just 3 "types" or are there an unknown number?